# Pra que serve a função pcntl_fork?

Tags: php, paralelismo

Eu estava procurando por alguma solução em PHP, onde eu pudesse executar um *script* sem esperar que determinada função que processa coisas demoradas tivesse que ser esperada para finalizar a execução do mesmo.

Me deparei com a função `pcntl_fork`. Vi que ela cria um processo paralelo, mas não entendi bem o que ela faz.

Alguém poderia me dar detalhes desta função?

Comment: Já descobri que essa geringonça não funciona com Apache :\

Comment: Você quer usar a biblioteca pthread correto?

Comment: @Everson sim, pena que parece não existir isso pro apache.

Comment: Na verdade existe sim a biblioteca PThread, eu até uso aqui. Porém apenas para envio de e-mail. Nunca usei diretamente na aplicação. Mas se quiser eu posso colocar como resposta a forma usar essa biblioteca.

Comment: @Everson pode ser. Eu apanhei pra instalar ela :\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Me deparei com a função `pcntl_fork`. Vi que ela cria um processo
>   paralelo, mas não entendi bem o que ela faz.

Não, houve um equívoco em tua interpretação. A função `pcntl_fork` não cria um processo paralelo, ela bifurca o processo e o divide em processos pai -> filhos.

Ela retorna, em caso de sucesso, o `PID` da `thread` `pai` e `0` para o `PID` dos `filhos`. Na documentação há um exemplo simples de como funciona:

```
$pid = pcntl_fork();
if ($pid == -1) {
     die('could not fork');
} else if ($pid) {
     // Processo pai
     pcntl_wait($status); // Protege contra processos zumbis 
} else {
     // Processos filhos
}
```

Conforme [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13105346/1432957), há algumas vantagens/desvantages:

- Comunicação entre processos é possível, via objeto serializado em memória compartilhada
- Sincronização através de [semáforos](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.sem.php) é possível
- `File descriptors` e `Database Conections` são compartilhados e isso pode causar problemas com frequência. Por exemplo: Conexões com o `DB` devem ser recriadas toda vez que um processo é bifurcado.
- Os processos `pai` devem esperar a finalização dos processos `filhos` ou será deixado processos "zumbis" em funcionamento.

Lembrando que `PHP` é uma linguagem de scripts e que programação "paralela" pode ser um pesadelo e de difícil manutenção.