# O que são Semáforos em programação?

Tags: terminologia, semáforo

Numa série de perguntas que fiz para tirar dúvidas a respeito de paralelismo, assíncronismo, threads e afins, acabei me deparando com diversos novos conhecimentos, e também diversos termos novos.

Nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210285/4995) por exemplo, alguém faz uma indicação do termo *semáforos*, quando cita vantagens e desvantagens de uma *bifurcação de processos*.

Mas o que seria semáforos na programação?

Ela está ligada a algum dos termos que citei no início dessa publicação?

<sub>**Nota:** Só conseguir encontrar referências em inglês, por isso fiz a pergunta aqui.</sub>

Comment: Relacionado: [Qual a diferença entre Semáforo e Monitor?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/208859/64969)

Comment: [Esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1957/64969) do [@Bigown](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/101/bigown) para [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1946/64969) do @Bigown fala bastante de semáforos

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Semáforo, é um conceito criado por [Dijkstra](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_Dijkstra) para solucionar conflitos de acessos concorrentes a um mesmo recurso por processos distintos.

Uma analogia para semáforo, seria uma boate: 
Ela contém uma capacidade máxima e que é assegurada pelo porteiro/segurança. Uma vez que a capacidade é atingida, ninguém pode entrar e se começa a formar filas na porta. Então, para cada indivíduo que deixa a boate, um outro tem sua passagem permitida a partir do início da fila.

Em programação, um semáforo é uma variável protegida que possui um valor inteiro e não negativo, e que possui as operações:

- Inicialização
- `V(s) = signal(s)`: Se o semáforo tiver `valor = 0` e possuir um processo em espera, o processo é ativado. Senão, o valor de semáforo é incrementado.
- `P(s) = wait(s)`: Decrementa o valor do semáforo. Se `valor = 0` o processo é colocado em espera.

Utilizando pseudo-código, temos:

```
inicialização(Semáforo S, Inteiro N){
    S = N;
}

V(Semáforo S){   //semáforo Signal
    Se(S != 0)
        S++;
    Senão
        desbloqueia_processo();
}

P(Semáforo S){    //semáforo Wait
    Se(S == 0)
        bloqueia_processo();
    S--;
}
```

**Fontes**:

- https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-6867/sync-27385/index.html
- https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sem%C3%A1foro_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)
- http://www.ece.ufrgs.br/~fetter/ele213/sem.pdf
- http://www.dca.ufrn.br/~adelardo/cursos/DCA409/node85.html
- http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/threads-sema.pdf

Comment: Apesar de não ser baladeiro, +1 pela boate ;)

Answer (score 6):

Em termos simples, um semáforo é uma indicação no código dizendo que algum recurso (pode ser um objeto, uma função, etc...) está sendo utilizado.

Pense da seguinte forma: 
Eu tenho uma função que faz a escrita em um leitor de cartões SD. 
Antes de utilizar a função eu consulto um semáforo (que no caso, pode ser uma variável global, ou algo parecido) e verifico se mais alguém está utilizando essa função.
Se a variável indica que a função não está em uso, eu posso utiliza-la.
Se a variável indica que a função está em uso, eu não posso.

Geralmente se utiliza semáforos em situações onde o programa tem várias threads executando, mas possui algum recurso que só pode ser utilizado por uma thread por vez.

Answer (score 4):

Sim!

Semáforo é um tipo de estrutura responsável controlar acesso de recursos em um ambiente multitarefas. Quando declarada ela indica quantas threads podem ter acesso a um determinado recurso. Todo semáforo conte dois métodos básicos P e o V. Quando vamos requisitar algo devemos chamar o método P(Parsen/Passar) que faz a verificação se é possível liberar o recurso. Após finalizar o método V(Vrygeren/Liberar) é chamado para avisar as demais threads que o recurso foi liberado. 
Vou deixar um exemplo da implementação de ambos métodos a seguir:

```
public synchronized void p () {
    if (this.recursos > 0)
        this.recursos--;
    else {
        this.esperando++;

        try {
           this.wait ();
        } catch (InterruptedException E){}
    }
}

public synchronized void v () {
    if (this.esperando > 0) {
        this.notify ();
        this.esperando--;
    } else
        this.recursos++;
}
```

Se ainda ficou alguma dúvida pode ler um pouco mais sobre os Semáforos nestes links:

1. [Praticando concorrência em Java! – Semáforos](http://brizeno.wordpress.com/tag/semaforos/)
2. [THREADS, SEMÁFOROS E DEADLOCKS – O JANTAR DOS FILÓSOFOS](https://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/threads-semaforos-e-deadlocks-o-jantar-dos-filosofos/)

Answer (score 2):

Semáforo é uma variável especial protegida (ou tipo abstrato de dados) que tem como função o controle de acesso a recursos compartilhados (por exemplo, um espaço de armazenamento) num ambiente multitarefa. Normalmente um semáforo indica quantos processos (ou threads) podem ter acesso a um recurso compartilhado.

> Um semáforo é uma variável, um mecanismo de sincronização sem espera ativa. Esta variável pode ser manipulada através de duas primitivas atómicas, isto é, que não podem ser interrompidas por processos.

As principais operações sobre semáforos são:

> Inicialização: Recebe um valor inteiro indicando a quantidade de processos que podem acessar um determinado recurso.
>   Operação wait ou P: Decrementa o valor do semáforo. Se o semáforo está com valor zero, o processo é posto para dormir.
>   Operação signal ou V: Se o semáforo estiver com o valor zero e existir algum processo adormecido, um processo será acordado. Caso contrário, o valor do semáforo é incrementado.

Link: https://www.revista-programar.info/artigos/threads-semaforos-e-deadlocks-o-jantar-dos-filosofos/