# qual é o objetivo dessas funções prefixadas por "msg_" em PHP?

Tags: php

Como citei  na minha pergunta  anterior sobre [semáforos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/211354), surgiu-me uma dúvida referente  [à essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/210285/4995), pois quando o autor da resposta cita sobre *Semáforos*, ele referencia esse [link da documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.sem.php) onde temos várias funções em PHP com o prefixo `msg_`.

Tenho a pequena impressão que isso refere-se à *message queues*, mas queria confirmar a utilidade disso em PHP, já que a documentação não é muito clara sobre as utilidades das funções.

Alguém saberia explicar por exemplo qual é a finalidades dessas funções abaixo?

```
msg_receive 
msg_remove_queue 
msg_send 
msg_set_queue 
msg_stat_queue
```

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação, dentro do conjunto de funções específicas para controle de processo, essa biblioteca de funções tem a finalidade provê funcionalidades para se trabalhar com System V IPC.

É possível manipular filas de mensagens, semáforos e memória compartilhada através dessas funções.

Especificamente falando sobre as funções com prefixo `msg_`, são funções utilizadas para trabalhar com filas de mensagens, usando IPC.

Essas funções só estão disponíveis em Sistema Operacional Linux.

Fiz esse [gist](https://gist.github.com/wallacemaxters/a2712a2f353703726b2bfbcb315cc68b) como exemplo, mas em breve coloco um exemplo melhor aqui.